# Is this type of sentence an Inversion?

Tags: inversion

I have heard this type of sentence with the same structure every time: 
'Beautiful as she is', 'Intelligent as he is...'

Is it grammatically correct and if it is what's this grammatical phenomenon called? 
How do you end such a sentence? 
I believe it's Inversion but I'm not sure.

For example with a sentence beginning like this 'Young as she is...' how would I end it?

Comment: The speaker is making a *concession*, i.e. conceding that he is intelligent, but then going on to state something that goes against what has been conceded.  Intelligent as he is, he still forgets to tie his shoelaces.

Answer (score 7):

These are not sentences but heavily reduced versions of much fuller clauses of the form

```
  [X  SUBJ BE as]   ADJ as SUBJ BE 
  [X   she is as] young as  she is
```

The construction *SUBJ BE as ADJ as SUBJ BE* may be paraphrased

```
  SUBJ BE so ADJ
   she is so young
```

"X" here is a term of the sort traditional grammars call *subordinating conjunctions* and contemporary grammars tend to call *prepositions*. X is usually understood to have the sense of either *because* or *although*.

Such clauses are typically employed as clausal modifiers with either a consequential (*because*) or a contrastive/concessive (*although*) sense. Which sense is intended is usually clear from the context:

> CONSEQUENTIAL: [**Because** she is as] Young as she is, she doesn't have the maturity for this position.
>
> CONCESSIVE:  [**Although** she is as] Young as she is, she's too old to play this part.

You will often encounter this sort of clause with the first *as* still in place:

> As young as she is, she's too old to play this part.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be able to tell you how it's called, but it is grammatically correct, and conveys a contradiction between the first and second propositions. A simple example, since you asked for it:

> Young as she is, she's already accomplished many things.

Despite the fact that she's only lived for so long, she's already made those years matter. This is equivalent to:

> Even though she is Young, she's already accomplished many things.

As TRomano pointed out, talking about **concession** is even more accurate.

Comment: I particularly enjoy the idiom "Be as it may..." instead of "It may be so, but..."

Comment: @MorganFR I've usually heard the phrase as "Be that as it may".

Comment: This sort of phrase can also be used in a non-concessive sense: *Young as she is, she doesn't have the maturity for this position.*

Comment: I've only read it in a concessive way so far, and automatically assumed it was purely designed for this purpose. Would you have a handy source on this matter ?

Comment: Yes sorry I did mean "be that as it may," I just typed it too fast