# The meaning of "Impressive as the achievements of Western technological science are, ..." in the context

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, as

> Impressive as the achievements of Western technological science are, there is no denying that they have been bought at a price, which includes increased nervous strain and destruction of the Earth's natural riches.

1.In this sentence, I guess "as" means equal of the next phrase...
Is it right?

2.and I can hardly understand the relevance of the two phrase(impressive~are,there~riches)..someone told me I can think 'a/ad as S V' as 'though S V a/ad' I want to know the reason why I have to understand like this way..,.not literally

Comment: It is a concessive structure.  Although the achievements are impressive,  they have a downside: nervous strain and a degraded environment.

Comment: Delicious as this chocolate cake is, I will eat only a little of it because the icing is very buttery and high in calories.

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90838/is-this-type-of-sentence-an-inversion.

Answer (score 2):

(as) {adjectival phrase} {as} {subject} {predicate}....

The initial "as" is optional.

> As fast as this train goes, we will still arrive late.
>
> Fast as this train goes, we will still arrive late.

Placing the adjective at the beginning of the sentence gives it great emphasis, such that we can paraphrase:

Agreed, this train is *very* fast...

The second part of the sentence states a contradictory fact set in opposition to the concession, so that we can paraphrase:

Agreed, this train is very fast -- but we will be late nonetheless.